# Program in Java to convert a date to serial number as done in Excel

Tags: java, excel, date

I have written a function but it does not give an actual O/P...

```
public int date(Object O) {
    if (O instanceof Date) {
        Date d1 = (Date) O;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d1);
        int dd, mm, yy;
        dd = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mm = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        yy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (dd == 29 && mm == 02 && yy == 1900)
            return 60;

        long nSerialDate = ((1461 * (yy + 4800 + ((mm - 14) / 12))) / 4)
                + ((367 * (mm - 2 - 12 * ((mm - 14) / 12))) / 12)
                - ((3 * (((yy + 4900 + ((mm - 14) / 12)) / 100))) / 4) + dd
                - 2415019 - 32075;

        if (nSerialDate < 60) {
            // Because of the 29-02-1900 bug, any serial date
            // under 60 is one off... Compensate.
            nSerialDate--;
        }

        return (int) nSerialDate;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

### Main class

```
p s v main(String args[]){
CommonFunctionsImpl cmp= new CommonFunctionsImpl();
    Date date1 = null;
      try {
        date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse("05/18/2008");

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("date-----"+cmp.date(date1));
}
```

**Output** `date-----39556`

**In Excel** `DATE(2008,5,18) = 39586.00`

My program O/P doesn't actually match with Excel O/P.

Comment: I am not into java but `39556` means you are getting `4/18/2008` instead of `5/18/2008(39586)` Maybe that is a clue and you can step though the code to see why is it taking it as the 4th month?

Comment: @siddharth- can u write an algo to implement it? i suppose u can.. :)

Comment: Yes I can but it will be in VB.Net/VBA/VB6/C# since I don't know java. And I am not sure how will it help you as the syntax is way too different?

Comment: syntax doesnt matter... kindly provide me whatever you are are comfortable with!

Comment: I see you have selected your answer. do you still need me to post an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right algorithm is already implemented in Apache POI.
Take a look at class [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html).

Also this description could be useful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214094/en-us

Comment: Can u give the api name where the serial number is returned?

Comment: The method you need is public static double getExcelDate(java.util.Date date)

Comment: A simple search for Apache POI download gives you: http://poi.apache.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the program is :

In the program, variable `mm(month)` is coming as 4 and O/P is coming for 4th month only.
*(The first month of the year is 0)*

To Solve this, you need to increase the month value.

```
    dd = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mm = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    yy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    //Solution for the issue
    mm++;

    if (dd == 29 && mm == 02 && yy == 1900)
        return 60;

    long nSerialDate = ((1461 * (yy + 4800 + ((mm - 14) / 12))) / 4)
            + ((367 * (mm - 2 - 12 * ((mm - 14) / 12))) / 12)
            - ((3 * (((yy + 4900 + ((mm - 14) / 12)) / 100))) / 4) + dd
            - 2415019 - 32075;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
Date begin = new Date(0, 0, 1); // 1900 based date
Date date = new Date(108, 4, 18); // your date

// There is 2 days offset from the calculated date and what you 
// expect so I added it on the result
System.out.println(2+(date.getTime()-begin.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
```

See [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) JavaDoc && Excel [Date](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/date-function-dax-HA102839075.aspx?CTT=1) Function Guide