# How to convert in modern C++ a double into a datetime

Tags: c++, excel, c++20, excel-dates

How to convert in modern C++ (C++11/14/17) a **double** into a date time using the [date.h](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library, when the double has been generated while exporting an Excel worksheet as a CSV file?

For instance, the datetime appearing in Excel:

21/08/2017 11:54

has been converted by Excel into the CSV file as the double:

42968.4958333333

Thanks.

**EDIT on 11/07/2019:** This questions is about the use of the [date.h](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library. The other questions pointed out as "possible duplicates" does not require the use of this library (see also the comment below by the author of the *date.h* library)

Comment: Depends on how Excel decides to convert the data to double, it would be a lot easier to help you if you could provide it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, the number given in the example is the result of the Excel conversion. I have no idea how excel convert this number, otherwise I would know the answer to my question.

Comment: @Borgleader I just edit my question to try to clarify it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5023663/214671

Comment: [Google helps you find the documentation](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=DATEVALUE+function)

Comment: [Bonus reading about the bizarre Excel 31/12/1899 epoch](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/)

Comment: If you use MFC/ATL, there is the very convenient [`COleDateTime` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38wh24td.aspx) which has a constructor that takes a `double` in this format.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XCmUzfuM I think..  `std::chrono` is still a bit uncivilized compared to `DateTime` classes in other languages like Java and C# and so on..

Comment: This question could not possibly be a duplicate of [date time conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022864/date-time-conversion) because this question asks how to use the [date.h](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library.  This library did not even exist when the other question was asked.  Nor has the other question been updated to ask about this newer library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [date.h](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), it could look like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
to_chrono_time_point(double d)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    using ddays = duration<double, days::period>;
    return sys_days{December/30/1899} + round<system_clock::duration>(ddays{d});
}

int
main()
{
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << to_chrono_time_point(42968.495833333333333333333) << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
2017-08-21 11:54:00.000000
```

This definition assumes that your mapping from 42968.4958333333 to 21/08/2017 11:54 is correct.  I see in one other place that the epoch is supposed to be 1899-12-31, not 1899-12-30.  In any event, once the correct epoch is found, this is how one would perform the computation.

Ah, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_bug explains the off-by-one error.  The writers of Excel purposely considered 1900 a leap year for the purpose of backwards compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3.

This output was generated on macOS where `system_clock::duration` is `microseconds`.  The output will be slightly different on other platforms where `system_clock::duration` has other units.

Aside:  At this range, the precision of an IEEE 64 bit `double` is coarser than `nanoseconds` but finer than `microseconds` (on the order of half of `microsecond`).

Comment: Howard: thanks again for your answer. I really appreciate the support to your date.h library.