# Convert timestamp with reference time to formatted time

Tags: c++, date-conversion

I want to convert a timestamp into a formatted time.
The timestamp is a double value (e.g. timestamp = 41274.043)  with reference date from 1.1.1900 00:00 and should return something like 02.01.2017 01:01.

I couldn't find anything about how to set the reference time properly. Any advice?
To customize date I would use strftime(), STL is necessary...

BR

jtotheakob

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516471/how-to-convert-in-modern-c-a-double-into-a-datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open source, header-only library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) it can be done like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
to_chrono_time_point(double d)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    using ddays = duration<double, days::period>;
    return sys_days{January/1/1900} + round<system_clock::duration>(ddays{d});
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << date::format("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M\n", to_chrono_time_point(41274.043));
}
```

This simply converts the `double` into a `chrono::duration` with a representation of `double` and a period of `days`, then rounds that `duration` into a `system_clock::duration`, and finally adds that duration to 1.1.1900 00:00.  The result is a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.

The `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` can be formatted with `date::format` from the same library as shown.  The output of this program is:

```
02.01.2013 01:01
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks Howard for your answer. So, am I understanding correctly that there is no STL header available at the moment?

Comment: That is correct.  Though this library has been voted into the draft C++20 standard.  It will be in the header `<chrono>` and `namespace std::chrono` instead of `"date.h"` and `date`.  I do not know when your vendor will offer this C++20 feature, but I hope within about a year.

Comment: Might be silly, but is there an explanation how to add your library in NetBeans8.2 (Windows10)?
Couldn't find a useful description. Curiously, I managed to add Boost library a few months ago, but this time it won't run...

Comment: I don't know anything about NetBeans.  But date.h is header-only and known to work with recent versions of Visual Studio.  Just include the header and it works.  If you also need time zone support (tz.h), then there's also a source file that needs compiling.  Detailed instructions (including Windows-specific) are here:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation